# How to use EJS template engine with NestJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, ejs

I would like to use EJS as my template engine in NestJS. With Express I can configure EJS in the main file like this:

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

How can I best implement this with NestJS? Nestjs does not ship with a `.set` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure that with the help of `app.setViewEngine('ejs')` in `main.ts`. First, install it:

```
npm i ejs
```

With the lines below, you would have told Express that the `public` directory will be used for storing static assets, `views` will contain templates, and the `ejs` template engine should be used to render HTML output.

```
// main.ts
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
    AppModule,
  );
  /*
     Here it's assumed that public and views are in the root directory,
     alongside src. You can put them wherever you want, 
     just use the correct path if you use another folder.
  */
  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
  app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
  app.setViewEngine('ejs');

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

And below is how you would render a template in a Controller. You are rendering `index.ejs` and passing `message` as a parameter.

```
// app.controller.ts
import { Get, Controller, Render } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @Get()
  @Render('index')
  root() {
    return { message: 'Hello world!' };
  }
}
```

Finally, you would use that passed `message` variable inside `index.ejs` like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= message %>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can read more on the official [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc).